# Use the PK as FK in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

How can i model in `hibernate` o table which the primary key is also the foreign key

as this schema :

```
CREATE TABLE policies (
   policy_id          int,
   date_issued        datetime,

   -- // other common attributes ...
);

CREATE TABLE policy_motor (
    policy_id         int,
    vehicle_reg_no    varchar(20),

   -- // other attributes specific to motor insurance ...

   FOREIGN KEY (policy_id) REFERENCES policies (policy_id)
);

CREATE TABLE policy_property (
    policy_id         int,
    property_address  varchar(20),

   -- // other attributes specific to property insurance ...

   FOREIGN KEY (policy_id) REFERENCES policies (policy_id)
);
```

1. Is this possible in hibernate mapping or the best is to separate
   them and use a new PK ?
2. and also it's okey if i use auto increment on the main table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. This is useful for one-to-one associations where you can have:

```
@Id
@Column(name="policy_id")
private policyId;

@MapsId
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "policy_id")
private Policy policy;
```

You can use AUTO-INCREMENT on the main table, which means you need to use an [IDENTITY](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/) generator in JPA/Hibernate.

The [@MapsId](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) allows you to share the same SQL column with the entity identifier property. It instructs Hibernate to use this column for resolving the `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne` association. Changes should always be propagated through the @Id property, rather than the to-one side (which is ignored during inserts/updates).

Comment: what mean `@MapsId` ?

Comment: thanks man it really help me because i used hibernate tools and it generate me a extra table with @Embeddable stuff.